# Shifting TextViews to the right in a ListView

Tags: java, android

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecQbu.jpg)
As you can see in the Image I provided , my 'column title' and 'column contents' are not in line.The contents of the column are shifting to the left.How can I rectify it?
My whole xml code is in ScrollView. It was working earlier  i.e. the column and it's contents were in a line , but now the contents are shifting to the left even when i'm not doing anything new than before.

my xml code:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3,4"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_background">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="253dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Banana(1/2 medium)"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_table_layout_row1_cal"
                    android:layout_width="192dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="55"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_table_layout_row1_con"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:hint=" Quantity or 0"
                    android:layo-ut_margin="1dp"
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:background="@drawable/tv_round_corners_with_white_background"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_table_layout_row1_tot"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_column="3"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Total"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the parent the `TextView` is in. You have a few options in XML:

- `LinearLayout`, `FrameLayout` - `android:layout_gravity="right"` (or `"end"` if minSdk > 16)
- `RelativeLayout` - `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`
- `ConstraintLayout`, `MotionLayout` - `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"`

This shifts the actual view to the right. If you want to shift the text, set `android:gravity="right"` (or `"end"` if minSdk > 16) on the `TextView` itself.

Comment: Can you refer to my edited question and help me please?